# phpstorm: change debug section color

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've got a custom dark theme for PhpStorm, everything is nice except debug section that has a red font that is not readable in context of a black background . is it possible to change **debug section**(not editor section) background and font color? 
 
by the way color ide plugin is installed

Comment: Not sure if it's what you mean, but is it one of the options in file > settings > editor > Colors & fonts > debugger? Or one of the Console options within the editor?

Answer (score 4):

Per the comment by @gabe3886...

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Debugger

Change the properties of "Breakpoint line" (see image below)

[image]